# How do encrypted authentication cookies prevent session hijacking?

Tags: encryption, cookies, session-cookies

Suppose a cookie say FB's authentication cookie is encrypted and sent to me. If i use tools like wireshark, Firesheep then I can sniff that encrypted cookie. I open a new browser and inject this encrypted cookie(using greasemonkey and some scripts) and eventually it's going to work. Whats the purpose of encryption here ?

Because the point is even after encrypting I am going to send the encrypted cookie each time I click something on facebook after logging in and the sniffing tools can get that. Pls explain ????

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about website security, but doesn't contain a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

most websites use cookie to identify user login, and yes, the cookie is visible to you. but every time you login in the website, the website would send a new encrypted cookie to you, your old/previous cookie would not be working. And cookie has a date to expire, the encryption on the cookie is to stop user calculating the cookie for login next time. If the user could have the formula for generating the cookie string, there would be no security for the website. cheers!
By the way, you should understand this for doing good things, don't do bad things, keep our Internet safe and tidy! thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if u got me exactly. let me explain..
I login to facebook
Fb sets an encrypted cookie on my machine
Then for each click I do on facebook this cookie is going to be transferred to FB server and only to FB by SameOriginPolicy.
Someone on the same n/w as mine can get this cookie easily using sniffers.so my point is what if he uses this cookie from his browser then he will be logged in to facebook automatically . so whats the point in encrypting ?

Comment: Hi, when you login FB, you are using HTTPS which will encrypt your browser content and cookie,make them unreadable, it's not easy for other people to see your cookie via sniffing. but, you are right, if they can capture all your cookie, it's possible for them to login as you in certain period time. that's why you should not install un-certified 3 party browser plugins. Http/https is stateless, the  cookie is your identifier, you should keep them safe.